# oracle SQL Hibernate one-to-one mapping returns NullPointerException

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I am developing an application and using Hibernate first time. I am trying to implement 1-2-1 mapping but it results in NullPointerException. I am using Oracle as backend.

Student Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="student_info")
public class Student_Info {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="sid", sequenceName="ids", initialValue=1, allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="sid")
    private int rollNo;

    @Column
    private String sname;

    public int getRollNo() {
        return rollNo;
    }
    public void setRollNo(int rollNo) {
        this.rollNo = rollNo;
    }
    public String getSname() {
        return sname;
    }
    public void setSname(String sname) {
        this.sname = sname;
    }
}
```

Student_detail Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="student_detail")
public class Student_detail {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="newGenerator")//name of the primary key generator
    @GenericGenerator(name="newGenerator", strategy="foreign", parameters={@Parameter(value="Student_Info", name="property")})
    private int rollno;
    private String phone;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="rollno")
    private Student_Info student_Info;

    public int getRollno() {
        return rollno;
    }

    public void setRollno(int rollno) {
        this.rollno = rollno;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public Student_Info getStudent_Info() {
        return student_Info;
    }

    public void setStudent_Info(Student_Info student_Info) {
        this.student_Info = student_Info;
    }
}
```

Main Class

```
Student_Info student_Info = new Student_Info();
student_Info.setSname("Vivek Singh");

Student_detail detail = new Student_detail();
detail.setPhone("2345678");     
detail.setStudent_Info(student_Info);

SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate/hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
Session session = factory.openSession();
session.beginTransaction();     

session.save(detail);
session.getTransaction().commit();

session.close();
factory.close();
```

Error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getPropertyValue(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:547)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getPropertyValue(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4636)
    at org.hibernate.id.ForeignGenerator.generate(ForeignGenerator.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:668)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:660)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:655)
    at com.hiber.Main.main(Main.java:23)
```

Tables are already there in DB with foreign key. one more thing I am using sequence to generate id, so I think it is causing the problem, I am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@GenericGenerator(name="newGenerator", strategy="foreign", parameters={@Parameter(value="Student_Info", name="property")})
```

Here you specified like `value = "Student_Info"` which is invalid in this mapping. you have to specify like `value = "student_Info".`(name of value not the name of class ). This fixed it.

Comment: Thanks its working now. This little mistake ruined my lots of time.